# Add folder name to exported file

Tags: python, directory, filenames

I'm hoping someone can assist.  I want to add the folder name to a file export so the exported filename is "combined_summary_of .xls" but can't seem to be able to add in the right reference name.  The list of folders does work but stuck at the folder name.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

df_list = list() # list of dataframes
folder = r"D:/summary_tables/"
os.chdir(folder)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for folder in folder:
        keyword = folder
        os.chdir("D:/summary_tables/")
        glob.glob("D:/summary_tables/"+ keyword + "/filtered*.xls")

#initialize a empty dataframe and append individual files
        all_data = pd.DataFrame()
        for f in glob.glob("D:/summary_tables/" +keyword + "/filtered*.xls"):
            df = pd.read_excel(f)
            all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)   
            all_data.head() 

#group all of the files together and sort 
            all_data2 = pd.concat([all_data]).groupby(['host_name_queried']).sum().reset_index() 
            all_data2 = all_data2.sort_values('Total_count', ascending=False)
            all_data2.head(n=10)
            all_data2['Total_nx_domain'] = all_data2['Total_nx_domain'].astype(float)

#send to xls
            import openpyxl
            all_data2.to_excel('D:/summary_tables/combined_summary_of_' +  '.xls', index=False)
            print ("file has been saved")
            all_data
```

Comment: Is filename is ``combined_summay_of_foldername.xls`` then in save  Excel add ``keyword`` to filename: ```all_data2.to_excel('D:/summary_tables/combined_summary_of_" + keyword + ".xls"```.

Comment: And put  that's block at ``for`` level

Comment: Thanks Juan.  I've tried that, I get an "ValueError:  No engine for filetype: ' ' "

Comment: Add engune: ```all_data2.to_excel('D:/summary_tables/combined_summary_of_" + keyword + ".xlsx",engine="openpyxl",index=False)```. Change extensiin to ``.xlsx``

Comment: It works but not doing what I intended.  I'm trying to loop through each folder and output the resulting combined_summary_of <folder name>  - I believe its only doing the last folder in the directory.

Comment: The last four lines (below comment line send  to xls) must be at same ``for`` level . Remove one indent.